# PHP & MYSQL Fatal Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been searching for about 3 hours now, and I see that a lot of people have a similar error, but I haven't found an answer on how to fix this problem yet. I see plenty of responses from people who say "your query must be returning false", but that doesn't help. I've only been using mysql and php for about a week now, so I'm very much an amateur.

I put the $count variable in there on purpose to see if my query would return the correct number of rows, and it does, but the while loop gives me the error. There are currently 2 rows in my table if that helps at all. There are also 3 total columns (id, User1, User2).

After doing a bunch of google searches on how to store multiple rows in an array, all of the responses say to use said while loop since fetch_assoc() only returns 1 row at a time.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this code, or what code I could use to load multiple rows of a mysql search into an array?

```
    $i = 0;
    $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE User1 = ? OR User2 = ?"); 
    $stmt1->bind_param("ss", $myuid, $myuid);

    if ($stmt1->execute()) {
        $stmt1->store_result();
        $count = $stmt1->num_rows;

        while(($row = $stmt1->get_result()->fetch_assoc()) !== FALSE){
            if ($row['User1'] == $myuid) {
                $friends[$i]= $row['User2'];
                $i++;
            } else if ($row['User2'] == $myuid){
                $friends[$i] = $row['User1'];
                $i++;
                }
        }

        $stmt1->close();
```

Comment: since you are using prepared statements, i think you want to bind results and then use `while ($stmt->fetch())`  .  How many columns are in the friends table? Is there any reason you don't list them instead of using *?
`

Comment: Try not to do things like `!== FALSE`. These functions are designed to return values that are logically true. Only employ that heavy-handed measure if you know you've got a tricky situation. Also, you're presuming `get_result()` returns a value you can act on which may  not be the case.

Comment: There are 3 columns total. I could list them out, but it doesn't make a difference for this code.

Comment: I got the !== FALSE thing off a website, but I started off without it. I get the same result either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work finally. @bio_sprite - thanks for the hint of binding the results. Here is the code that I used:

```
    $friends = array(); 
    $i = 0;
    $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT User1, User2 FROM friends WHERE User1 = ? OR User2 = ?"); 
    $stmt1->bind_param("ss", $myuid, $myuid);

    if ($stmt1->execute()) {
        $stmt1->bind_result($User1, $User2);

        while($stmt1->fetch()){

            if ($User1 != $myuid) {
                $friends[$i]= $User1;
                $i++;
            } else if ($User2 != $myuid){
                $friends[$i]= $User2;
                $i++;
                }
        }

        $stmt1->close();

        return $friends;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fetch()` for getting the result of your query

```
    $i = 0;
    $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE User1 = ? OR User2 = ?"); 
    $stmt1->bind_param("ss", $myuid, $myuid);

    if ($stmt1->execute()) {
        $count = $stmt1->rowCount();;

        while($row = $stmt1->fetch()){   // you can also try $result = $sth->fetchAll(); for getting all the result 
            if ($row['User1'] == $myuid) {
                $friends[$i]= $row['User2'];
                $i++;
            } else if ($row['User2'] == $myuid){
                $friends[$i] = $row['User1'];
                $i++;
                }
        }

        $stmt1->close();
```

Also for getting count `rowCount()` would give you the number of rows fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like I'm not getting any data when I use fetch(). Maybe the rest of the syntax is off, but the $row['User1'] and $row['User2'] calls return null values. I was also not able to get rowCount() to work. I noticed you put 2 semicolons, but it still returned an error when I took one of them off.